# Percent-width based horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I need help figuring out how to build a horizontal ul-li-based navigation.
The tricky part with it is, that **all** sizes have to be in percent. No px, no em.
Furthermore all list items should be equal width and fill the whole ul.
Another problem with this, at least with my attempts, is that there are 7 list items, which give me an ugly 14.28...% for each of them - which in my attempts so far resulted in the main content area being around 1-2px off, depending on the browser window size.

Here's a sketch of the layout I'm working on:
[link to the image (since I don't have enough reputation yet)](http://img.flashtux.org/img1332a1329f8fxfc69fca8.png)

Where I am at the moment:

```
<ul id="#main_menu">
    <li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">One</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Two</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Three</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Four</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Five</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Six</a></li><li class="main_menu_li"><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
</ul>

#main_menu{
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: auto 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
overflow: auto;
}

.main_menu_li{
display: inline;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 14.28%;
}

.main_menu_li>a{
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #fff;
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Problem with this code is, that there's still room to the right within the ul.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance for your efforts!

Comment: Working on an alternative solution.

Comment: Take a look at [HorizontalNav](http://sebnitu.github.com/HorizontalNav/), a pretty small jQuery plugin designed exactly for this type of design.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Thanks for the suggestion! I have thought about using JS/jQuery for the job - but something in my head keeps telling me to use the correct tool for the job, which would be CSS. Therefore I'm very fond of Bram Vanroy's answer. I'm gonna implement that in a minute and let you guys know how it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of **CSS3 magic** this is very well possible.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7D2hB/1/).
Important CSS:

```
nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 12.28%; /* for older browsers that don't support calc */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 7);
    width: -moz-calc(100% / 7);
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}
```

As you can see, I added a jQuery fallback. Unfortunately JSFiddle doesn't seem to work in IE10's IE8 mode, so I can't test whether it works or not. But, it should!

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/calc) the following browsers support `calc()`:

- FF4.0 and higher (`-moz-` prefix)
- IE9.0 and higher
- Chrome 19.0 and higher (`-webkit-` prefix)
- Opera does **NOT** support `calc` in its most modern browser (12.1)
- See the link for further information

Comment: This looks very promising - gonna work it into the actual page and let you know. BIG THANKS!

Comment: Are there always 7? The calc() is **completely** unnecessary and a very bad example usage.

Comment: @Rudie Do explain yourself. I don't see how it is unnecessary. It is needed when you want a pixel-perfect menu. Manual percentual values will always give blank space.

Comment: @HaenslD. And when there are more than 7, you just change the value from `7` to whatever is needed.

Comment: Where did you get "It is needed when you want a pixel-perfect menu."? I see none o that on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

Comment: @Rudie Well obviously ... They won't state all the applications of `calc()`, that would be just stupid. How else are you going to create a pixel-perfect dynamic menu without using `flex` (which is too much code for what you need imo)? Also, you didn't answer my question. Why is it unnecessary when it is less code and why is it a bad example?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy I like calc(), using it at quite a few places now. Your solution did the trick for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @HaenslD. You're welcome. Note that only modern browsers can use this! Also, you might wanna upvote this to bypass this (imo unwise) downvote.

Comment: @BramVanroy I would've upvoted this a long time ago if I had enough reputation, need 15 to do so ;)

Comment: @HaenslD. Ah, I see. Thanks anyway. Added some extra information. Good luck with it!

Comment: @Bram Vanroy So how did you know? Don't just say things. Substantiate it. Quote a source. Why does it work like that? The `%` work PERFECTLY for me too, on all browsers that understand `calc()`. Don't use `12.28%`. Use `14.2857142%`. (Where did you get 12.28??) Now how can `calc()` work better than that percentage? If you know, please do tell.

Comment: @Rudie what in God's name is your problem. First of all **you keep refusing to explain why this is *a very bad example usage* ** and it's pissing me off. Don't stay stuff like that if you are only mad. Secondly, here is why: http://i50.tinypic.com/1zafiw.png Pixel perfect. Thirdly, yes, you could go around noting the width of an element to x numbers after the comma, but is never as precise as `calc` unless keep noting all numbers after the comma until infinity. Also, for future improvements your "percentage solution" is extremely bad. In my case, you could just change the `7` into `8`.

Comment: @Bram You wouldn't have to change 7 to 8 if you'd use flexbox or table layout. Bad usage because calc() doesn't work better than %, so it's unnecessary (this isn't calc()'s function). Until you can back up that calc actually takes care of that pixel perfection with more than a... picture... I stand by my -1. And when you do, I'll change it to a +1, because calc() doing that, would be boss.

Comment: @Rudie Oh my God. that picture is a screenshot of a fiddle I made. And yes, flex would be the better solution, I agree on that. But **not** table, nor a simple percentage as you said. Well, I'm done. If you don't want to believe it, fine. Let it be.µ

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display: table`:

```
#main_menu{
    display: table;
}

.main_menu_li{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 14.28%;
}

.main_menu_li>a{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: One should avoid table-displays at all times.

Comment: @BramVanroy, can you please explain that?

Comment: table-layout at least seems to do what I want - but now I have problems getting the links to fill the whole list item.
I'm also a little uncomfortable with table-displays. Furthermore, as far as I know it'll break IE.

Comment: I was taught the following. `display: table` is merely a value that is automatically assigned to tables, as is `table-cell` for table cells. By assigning this value to an element such as a div, the browser incorrectly thinks the element is a table. As we have come to know, tables are **only** to be used for data that one would use in Excel or spread sheets. Hence, semantically a `table` display is not preferred if other solutions are at hand.

I am sorry if my remark was rather harsh. I didn't mean it so.

Comment: @HaenslD., give your `<a/>` a `display: block`. And it's compatible since IE8. For IE7 and less use conditional comments and a fallback.

Comment: @BramVanroy, nevermind! In this case, it is a good solution I think. And in general, I don't see the problem with `display: table`. So I can't agree, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell thanks for the answer - it seems to work. I'd prefer avoiding `display: table`, though. Maybe someone else has an idea how to avoid it and still get the desired layout?

Comment: Don't avoid `display: table`. Why would you? It's perfect for this scenario. This is why you can give any element `display: table`. Use it.

Comment: @Rudie Well, I guess I'm with team Bran Vanroy on this. In my coding philosophy tables ought not be used when not displaying tables ;-)

Comment: Then why is there a table display?? I can't believe this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: @Rudie There is a table display ... **for tables**.

Comment: @Bram Yeah so why does display: block exist? Blocks are already blocks. To change layout with CSS. Excellent stuff. It's why these days we can influence the shadow DOM with CSS. The browser makes everything with CSS, so we can fake it perfectly with CSS. Anyway, I quit.

Comment: @Rudie `block` exists ... for **block elements**. I don't understand why this is so hard to comprehend.

Comment: Wow, what a discussion. Sorry I didn't go with you, was out. What ever does the job for Haensl is good. Just one last thought: CSS knows no semantic. It would be absolutely wrong using an HTML `<table/>` for this. But a `display` statement with whatever value is absolutely appropriate. Or, displaying a `<span/>` as `block` would be wrong too. There are facts and opinions, and those are not implicitly the same. @Rudie, thanks for your efforts! Over and out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is another alternative. This one is even less compatible, but just to show you and because you are uncomfortable with using `display: table`:

```
#main_menu
{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    table-layout: auto;
}

#main_menu > li
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 14.28%;
}

#main_menu > li > a
{
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QRCT/2/) (tested in Chrome).

Comment: It's changed so many times, I surprise myself by being right.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell Thanks for your efforts! As you stated yourself - this is even less compatible, therefore I won't use it.